# Load local gif in swift get memory warning

Tags: ios, swift, gif

I have an expandable and collapsalbe tableview which shows multiple GIF file when it expand. At a certain time, when i expand multiple section again and again it crashed with memory warning when reached to 600 MB space.

My implementation :

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50) 

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

           let imageData = try! Data(contentsOf: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "compile_animatiion", withExtension: "gif")!)
            //imggview.image = UIImage.gif(data: imageData)
            imageView.image =  UIImage.gifImageWithData(imageData) 
            cell.addSubview(imageView)
        }
    }

    cell.addSubview(imageView)
   }
```

My code is using class UIImage+Gif , you can get it from git easily. I need the exact technqiue to avoid this memory warning.

Sample Source : drive.google.com/open?id=1tlVwaOfWoAronF91YykUtDy_c0iLhAzq

Answer (score 1):

**Improvements**:
1. Avoid creating infinite image views in method `cellForRowAt`.
2. Share the global gif image data to all reused cells.

**Code**:

```
private var _gifImageData:UIImage?
var gifImageData:UIImage! {
    get{
        if (_gifImageData != nil) {
            return _gifImageData
        }
        else{
            let imageData = try! Data(contentsOf: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "compile_animatiion", withExtension: "gif")!)
            _gifImageData = UIImage.gifImageWithData(imageData)
            return _gifImageData
        }
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellID", for: indexPath)
    let tagOfGifImageView = 1283
    if cell.viewWithTag(tagOfGifImageView) == nil {
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
        imageView.tag = tagOfGifImageView
        imageView.image = self.gifImageData
        cell.addSubview(imageView)
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: I have 44 separate gif. Same issue still :(